# Permission denied / Parse-migration

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, migration, parse-server, mlab

While following this guide(https://parse.com/migration), I run this command, as indicated, to check that things are working as expected:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: MY_APP_ID" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"score":1337,"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}' \
  http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/GameScore
```

And I get this message:

```
{"code":119,"error":"Permission denied for action create on class GameScore."}
```

Where do I need to set the permissions, so that it is no more denied?

Comment: Can you check in MongoDB if you have permissions to perform all the operations (create,find,delete etc.)

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I checked, a few hours ago now. And as you say I didn't have create permissions. But in order to make it work I had to set this:    "create": {"*": true}. Giving the permission only to the unique user I can see, for some reason didn't work.

Comment: before your checks at parse.class level you should verify the mongo connection using some mongo client. Once you have verify connect to mongo, go back to parse-server and GET an existing OID in one of the parse classes that were migrated. Then POST to one of those classes . Then try POST on a new class such as 'Gamescore'.